# how to inherit this javascript function?

Tags: javascript, function, class

How to build inheritance between two javascript function ?

Example:

```
    var jsApp = function() {

      return {
        init : function() {            
          console.log('jsApp init ...');
        },
        togglePanel : function () {
          console.log('togglePanel run ...');           
        },
        show : function() {
          console.log('show ...');
        },
      };
    }();
    
    
    var webApp = function() {
    
      return {
        init : function() {
          console.log('webApp init ...');
        },
        togglePanel : function () {
          console.log('togglePanel2 run ...');
        },
      };
    }();
```

How to fix webApp to inherit jsApp and let

webApp.show();

output 'show ...'

Comment: What makes you think that this should be possible?

Comment: Because it is possible theoretically. Prototype based language can achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) to create an object inheriting from `jsApp`, then add `webApp`'s properties to it (perhaps with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)); see the indicated changes below:

```
var jsApp = function() {

  return {
    init : function() {            
      console.log('jsApp init ...');
    },
    togglePanel : function () {
      console.log('togglePanel run ...');           
    },
    show : function() {
      console.log('show ...');
    },
  };
}();


var webApp = function() {

  return Object.assign(Object.create(jsApp), {
//       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    init : function() {
      console.log('webApp init ...');
    },
    togglePanel : function () {
      console.log('togglePanel2 run ...');
    },
  });
// ^
}();
```

Comment: Much Thanks for T.J.
We use it as our frontend jsApplet.
T.J.'s answer build the inheritance between jsApplets.
It really helps ^___^

Answer (score 0):

This is based on `Douglas Crockford` article. You can create a function `object`  which takes an old object as a parameter and returns an empty `new object` that inherits from the old one. An then you can add your additional method on that object.

When you call a method on new object it first looks like its own and if it does not find it then it try to find it in its prototype chain.

```js
function object(o) {
    function F(){};
    F.prototype = o;
    return new F();
}

var jsApp = {
    init : function() {            
      console.log('jsApp init ...');
    },
    togglePanel : function () {
      console.log('togglePanel run ...');           
    },
    show : function() {
      console.log('show ...');
    }
};

let webApp = object(jsApp);

webApp.init = function() {
  console.log('webApp init ...');
};

webApp.togglePanel = function () {
  console.log('togglePanel2 run ...');
};

webApp.init();
webApp.show();
```

Here is the article link:-

http://crockford.com/javascript/prototypal.html

Comment: There's been no need for that `object` function since 2009 when [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) was added to the standard library.

Answer (score -1):

please specify what exactly you are trying to achieve by making webApp inherit from jsApp. To make webApp.show() output 'show...' you can simply use this assignment statement as below:

`webApp.show = jsApp.show;`

Comment: This is what we called "jsApplet". Each SPA application will has one jsApplet to make SPA runs. Inheritance of jsApplet can make we reuse codes.